# WebdriverIo- Focus doesn’t return to browser after closing a pop up window

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

Here is the scenario I am automating however execution stops after step 3

1. Enter user name/Pwd on login page
2. Click submit button > opens a pop up window >> enter data in input box on pop up window and HIT OK button
3. Pop up is closed and a new page is displayed.
4. Verify elements on newly displayed page.

Issue: unable to locate any item, tried getting browser handle, wait until, tried getting browser.geturl.

Basically as soon as pop up window is closed, No step is executed. Execution will stop and after some time I see error in console

JavaScript heap out of memory.

Other details
Node version - 12
Webdriver 6.4.0
Browser - chrome 100.04896

EDIT: after debugging, found an exception. Session closed/target window is already closed. not sure why this exception is thrown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to do something like this?

```
const window = browser.getWindowHandle();

browser.switchToWindow(window);
```

or

```
browser.switchToParentFrame()
```

or

```
browser.switchToFrame()
```

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the issue, tried all this - unable to locate any item, tried getting browser handle, wait until, tried getting browser.geturl. 

Basically no command working releated to browser.

Comment: Hi... i debugged it and found the session is being closed when then pop up is closed. not sure why its happening. can someone please suggest solution?